# Github curl request to filter issues

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to use Github APIs to fetch a list of issues.

I need to filter issues on below condition

I need to get all **open issues** within a **specific date range** and has "sss" as **label** and title with few keywords.

I have not tried this all in one single query. Going step by step.

1. Filtering by date range

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${GHE_TOKEN}" \
  https://github.com/api/v3/repos/alchemy/storage/issues?state=all | jq '.[] | select(.created_at >= "2023-06-01" and .created_at <= "2023-07-13")'
```

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${GHE_TOKEN}" \
  https://github.com/api/v3/repos/alchemy/storage/issues?created:2023-06-02..2023-07-13
```

Both did not work
gives me wrong result. May I know what is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gh` CLI tool:

```
gh issue list --label sss --state open --json title,createdAt --jq '.[] | select(.createdAt >= "2023-05-01") | select(.title | contains ("KEYWORD"))'
```